# Child docked window

Tags: wpf, window, dock

Greetings, 
I would like to have child window docked next to my parent window. If I move parent window, child window should be also moved. The image below should explain what i would like to achieve: 
http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/1305/childdockedwindow.jpg 
Can someone help me please. I'm writing in WPF. Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `Window.LocationChanged` events and `Window.SizeChanged` events on the main window.  When either of these events fires, compute the new location for the child window.

Here is the idea:

```
var mainWindow = ...;
var childWindow = ...;

var handler = new EventHandler(() =>
{
  childWindow.Top = mainWindow.Top;
  childWindow.Left = mainWindow.Left + mainWindow.Width;
});

mainWindow.LocationChanged += handler;
mainWindow.SizeChanged += handler;
```

You may also need code that removes `handler` from both events when the child window no longer needs to be docked or is no longer shon.